# Delete tag in uncontrolled "ChipInput" using react hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form to handle form values, Its working fine for all other input types like TextFeild, Select from material but facing issues with "material-ui-chip-input" as adding tag working fine but not able to delete tag on click of cross button or hitting backspace. I'm struggling on this from a long.  Anyone please help in it.

```
import React from "react";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";

import ChipInput from "material-ui-chip-input";

const ReactHookFormChips = ({
  name,
  label,
  control,
  defaultValue,
  children,
  rules,
  error,
  chipsError,
  ...props
}) => {
  const labelId = `${name}-label`;
  return (
    <FormControl {...props}>
      <Controller
        as={
          <ChipInput
            label={label}
            helperText={chipsError}
            error={error}
          />
        }
        name={name}
        control={control}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        rules={rules}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
};
export default ReactHookFormChips;
```

calling this component like

```
<ReactHookFormChips
  id="levelLabel"
  name="tags"
  label="Select Tags"
  control={control}
  defaultValue={[]}
  margin="normal"
  error={!!errors?.tags}
  rules={{ required: true }}
  chipsError={errors?.tags && "Tag is required."}
/>
```

Comment: you probably want to use `render` prop and see what's the value is passing down.

Comment: Yes I fixed it using render prop, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it using render prop.

```
import React from "react";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";

import ChipInput from "material-ui-chip-input";

const ReactHookFormChips = ({
  name,
  label,
  control,
  defaultValue,
  children,
  rules,
  error,
  chipsError,
  ...props
}) => {
  const labelId = `${name}-label`;
  return (
    <FormControl {...props}>
      <Controller
        render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) =>
          <ChipInput
            onChange={onChange}
            label={label}
            helperText={chipsError}
            error={error}
          />
        }
        name={name}
        control={control}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        rules={rules}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
};
export default ReactHookFormChips;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. It solved the issue, however, I added `defaultValue={[]}` and `rules={{ required: true }}` to, `<Controller>`, so that it worked without a hitch. Writing it down for my future self. :D